# BDD Are scenarios exclusive?

Tags: bdd, scenarios

If two scenarios can occur at the same time, does that (always/ever) constitute a third scenario?

My current thinking is that they are not necessarily exclusive (depends on the scenario). If you have two scenarios that could occur at the same time that they would only require a third scenario if the Given/When/Then steps do not merge implicitly or if one scenario takes precedence over the other.

This question has arisen whilst thinking about scenarios for what is essentially a form of injection in which Collections of objects get injected into another object ( https://github.com/jameskennard/mockito-collections ). So given the two scenarios "*Class of object under test has a List of collaborators*" and "*Class of object under test has a Set of collaborators*". Both could occur at the same time so a third scenario could be "*Class of object under test has a List and a Set of collaborators*". But it doesn't feel right, it's just too verbose, I think the Given/When/Then steps would be seen to merge implicitly. (Have a bad feeling I may have just answered my own question)

Anyone have any differing thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key here is the behavior. The potential third scenario (*"Class of object under test has a List and a Set of collaborators"*) that you're asking about is of course real but the behavior is already covered by the other two scenarios so I'd say there is no need to write another scenario.

If the combination of givens was to result in different behavior there would certainly be a third scenario but I believe the two you have cover the behavior you're looking to define.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that was definitely the way I was leaning!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, your sentences above are describing *state* rather than *behavior*.

What is the different outcome you get in each of the different contexts? I would expect something like this:

```
Given my CUT has five collaborators
When I do my thing with the class
Then it should use each collaborator in turn.

Given my CUT has five collaborators
And the fourth and fifth collaborators are identical
When I do my thing with the class
Then it should only use the fourth collaborator once.
```

That would illustrate the different *behavior* of the list (ordered) and the set (no duplicates).

If those two elements are truly beneficial independently, then yes, they're two separate scenarios. If they both have to be present for the class to have any value, I'd merge them into one:

```
Given my CUT has five collaborators
And the fourth and fifth collaborators are identical
When I do my thing with the class
Then it should use each collaborator in turn
And it should only use the fourth collaborator once.
```

An example of two simultaneous benefits might be getting cash out of an ATM, in which the cash is delivered and the account is also debited. You couldn't do either of those independently. Offering a receipt for the transaction would be a separate benefit, as it doesn't *need* to occur for an ATM to be of value. Hope this helps to make the distinction.

Comment: Thanks Lunivore, I was worried that using the examples I provided would cause confusion. I am not describing behaviour of the CUT. I am describing the behaviour of an addon to a testing framework (haence the confusion in terminology). The sentences, or rather the scenario names, are inline with Dan North's article [link](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/) describing how to name scenarios. The name of the story is behaviour orientated.

Your example using the traditional ATM type scenarios is interesting. And it does illustrate that the scenarios do not have to be exclusive. Thankyou :)

Comment: Ah, when I'm writing a library I usually create a little app to use as the example for the library - for instance, we used the Game of Life for JBehave, and I have a pet shop for the automation tool WiPFlash. Then you just write scenarios / unit level examples for the app. That would probably work for Mockito, too.

Comment: I'd tried that approach - but just managed to confuse myself lol. I found that the examples just resulted in muddled thinking. This is probably because I'm working on something so small, and because I'm so useless at coming up with good examples!

Comment: What was the example that made you think you might need this? Can you create something similar? I find this also helps with really clear, usuable interfaces. Ideally BDD doesn't start with testing - it's about providing an example of how to use something, and showing why you might want to.